# php mostar el numero de veces que aparece una relacion

Tags: php, sql

Hola muy Buenas que tal tengo un problema en php y no quiero guardar el valor en la base de datos, me gustaría saber si conocen alguna manera para ver las veces que aparece una relación dedos tablas en la base de datos es decir yo tengo una clase y otra que se relaciona con otra clase la cual me gustaría saber cuantas veces esta relacionada en la bd para así saber si esta disponible o no gracias y un saludo.  estoy utilizando silverstripe 3.

Answer (score 0):

Hola no entendí muy bien que es lo que queres. Pero calculo que haciendo un select * from con un inner joinlo convertis en un array y preguntas si NO esta vacío le haces un count();

EJEMPLO

$sql = "select * FROM tabla1 INNER JOIN tabla2 WHERE tabla1.id = tabla2.id"

$resultado = mysql_query($conexion, $sql);

while($registro= mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)){

}

$numeroDeRegistros = count($registro);